# How to click join button of Microsoft Teams meeting session opened on browser programmatically using javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I want to click Join button of teams meeting opened on browser using javascript.
How to click Join button of Microsoft Teams meeting session opened on browser programmatically using javascript

Comment: It does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Join button is part of a Microsoft Teams product. Hence it does not seem like you can access it using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from the comment section:

Join button is the part of a Microsoft Teams product and it's event handler is not exposed to develop 3rd party apps for now. Hence you can not access it using JavaScript.

Comment: We can still access it by creating chrome extension and accessing DOM using JS